# Integrating $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $\frac{-1}{1+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Given the idea of antiderivatives, how do I reconcile the following?

$$ F(x) = \int_0^x \frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt = \arctan x $$

$$ G(x) = \int_0^x\frac{-1}{1 + t^2}\,dt \neq \text{arccot }x \iff \frac{d}{dx}\big[\text{arccot }x\big] = \frac{-1}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: $G(x)=\operatorname{arccot} x+C$. You need to determine the constant.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that $\int\frac{dx}{x^2+1}=\arctan x$?

Answer (score 2):

Since by definition $G(0)=0$, $G(x)=-\arctan x=\operatorname{arccot}x-\frac{\pi}{2}$.